# Como puedo recorrer un XML nodo a nodo

Tags: xml, delphi

Tengo el siguiente XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tv generator-info-name="Panel IPTV" generator-info url="http://tvla.xyz:25461/">
    <channel id="AandE.mx">
        <display-name>A&amp;E [0]</display-name>
        <icon src="http://www.chileiptv.xyz/logos/153.jpg"/>
    </channel>
    <channel id="AXN.mx">
        <display-name>AXN [0]</display-name>
        <icon src="http://www.chileiptv.xyz/logos/157.jpg"/>
    </channel>
    <channel id="AztecaCinema.mx">
        <display-name>Azteca Cinema HD [0]</display-name>
        <icon src="http://www.chileiptv.xyz/logos/158.jpg"/>
    </channel>
    <channel id="Azteca13.mx">
        <display-name>Azteca 13 [0]</display-name>
        <icon src="http://www.chileiptv.xyz/logos/22.jpg"/>
    </channel>
    <channel id="Azteca7.mx">
        <display-name>Azteca 7 [0]</display-name>
        <icon src="http://www.chileiptv.xyz/logos/23.jpg"/>
    </channel>
</tv>
```

Hago el recorrido de los nodos con la siguiente rutina:

```
var
  StartItemNode, item: IXMLNode;
  id: string;
begin
  uqChannels.Close;
  uqProgramacion.Close;
  try
    usVaciarProgramacion.Execute;
    if XMLDoc.DocumentElement.NodeName = 'tv' then
    begin
      StartItemNode := XMLDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.FindNode('channel');
      item := StartItemNode;
      while item.NodeName = 'channel' do
      begin
        id := item.Attributes['id'];
        item.NextSibling;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    uqChannels.Open;
    uqProgramacion.Open;
  end;
end;
```

Pero el recorrido no sale del primer nodo.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder realizar la iteración sobre el "hermano" debes recuperar el valor

```
item := item.NextSibling;
```

Al hacer esto, item recupera el valor del siguiente nodo. Con esto ya te salen los siguientes nodos. Pero hay que tener en cuenta que al final item no estará asignado cuando no haya mas nodos. Por lo que en el bucle hay que asegurarse que esté asignado. Quedaría así:

```
while assigned(item) and (item.NodeName = 'channel') do
begin
    id := item.Attributes['id'];
    //¿No habría que hacer algo on id?
    item := item.NextSibling;
end;
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Id va a una tabla

Comment: Funciona correctamente, gracias

Comment: Me alegro @MiguelMolina. Si te ha funcionado, ¿Puedes aceptar la respuesta como válida? Gracias.